# Time consuming computation that needs to return multiple values at different times

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, websocket

I have this controller that handles a request which needs a lot of computing. The computation takes time and produces multiple values at different times during the computation that I need to send to my frontend as soon as the values are computed. I understand that a controller in spring only returns once.

Is it possible to somehow, when I receive a request in my spring-boot backend, set up something similar to a stream/channel between spring and my angular frontend. Then while I'm doing the computation continuously stream to the frontend instead of having to return all at once?

I've been looking at websockets a bit but it doesn't seen to be the solution as I have to send things to the frontend while still doing computation on the backend.

Comment: Did u try to use another thread to ?

Comment: How do you mean? Doing the computation on a separate thread while sending from another to frontend as soon as the values are computed? How would I send information to frontend multiple times from the other thread? @Xalion

Comment: Websocket helps you send the information from back-end to front-end right? The other part you'd need to do is in the computation thread, periodically save the status of the job to one of the shared memory space (DB, cache, etc), then use the Websocket to update client based on that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to kick off the operation in a thread or other backend task, and immediately return an ID to the client that identifies the task.  The client can then make periodic calls to get the state of the task with any updated information. Each call can return immediately, or "hang" until the next piece of data is available, cutting down on calls made and latency.

Another method is HTML5 server-sent events, which are made for this type of operation but I have not used them yet.  You can read about them here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

> The idea behind SSEs may be familiar: a web app "subscribes" to a stream of updates generated by a server and, whenever a new event occurs, a notification is sent to the client.